# How do I connect two sibling components in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have made one timer component and want to use it in two different places.

I want that if I start the timer at one place it should automatically start at the other and vice versa.

Using *@Output* and *@ViewChild* didn't work for me.

Comment: I think you can use singleton service

Comment: If you share working sample I can work on it. you can create stackblitz sample

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Sorry I can't share the code. Its a very small part in a vast project. Recreating it will be very time consuming. I know about the concept of Singleton and that wont be possible since there are thousands of requestIds and there is a separate timer for each!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state management or save time in localstorage and fetch the time from there. This way, you can show the time anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the time variable in a service (outside the timer component), and so, all instances of the component will use the same time...

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I prefer you to use NGRX Module in angular with Subject for Sibiling.

For more info, checkout this out https://ngrx.io/guide/store